# how to play one video in view pager with exo player

Tags: android, android-viewpager, exoplayer

i am making a app where i am playing videos with exo player in view pager but problem is that i am not able play one video at a time. all videos playing there at a time .i am not unable to pause videos on swipe.please help.

```
**this is my activity where i am setting data in view pager**

 ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),list);


    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**this is my view pager**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<VideosModel> list;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<VideosModel> list) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.list=list;
}

// Returns total number of pages
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

// Returns the fragment to display for that page
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return GlobalFragment.newInstance(list.get(position).getVideo());
}
```

}

**this is my fragment where i am getting video url and play in exo player**

```
public class GlobalFragment extends Fragment {

public static String video_url;
public static ExoPlayer player;
private PlayerView my_player_view;

public GlobalFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static GlobalFragment newInstance(String title) {
    GlobalFragment fragmentFirst = new GlobalFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(Commn.video_url,title);


    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    video_url=getArguments().getString(Commn.video_url);


    Log.e("Videoss","Videoss"+video_url+"");


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_global, container, false);

    iniViews(view);
    setDimension();

    playVideo();


    return view;
}

private void iniViews(View view) {
    my_player_view=view.findViewById(R.id.my_player_view);
    my_player_view.setRepeatToggleModes(10);
}

private void playVideo() {
    try {


        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getActivity(), trackSelector);

        Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(video_url);

        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoURI, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        my_player_view.setPlayer(player);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("MainAcvtivity"," exoplayer error "+ e.toString());
    }
}
private void setDimension() {

    float videoProportion = getVideoProportion();
    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    float screenProportion = (float) screenHeight / (float) screenWidth;
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = my_player_view.getLayoutParams();

    if (videoProportion < screenProportion) {
        lp.height= screenHeight;
        lp.width = (int) ((float) screenHeight / videoProportion);
    } else {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth * videoProportion);
    }
    my_player_view.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
private float getVideoProportion(){
    return 2f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int pager fragment layouts I define this:

```
                        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/playerView"/>
```

then in fragment onCreateView I added these lines:

```
        PlayerView playerView = v.findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        playerView.getLayoutParams().width = ListPager.widthPixels;
        playerView.getLayoutParams().height = ListPager.widthPixels;
        if(player!=null)
            player.release();
        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(App.applicationContext).build();
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url);
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        player.prepare();
        player.play();
```